# The type or namespace name 'boolean' could not be found

Tags: c#

For the following code in my home work shows an error The type or namespace name 'boolean' could not be found

```
          class LinkedList
   {
private Node first;
public LinkedList()
{
    first = null;
}
public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (first == null);
}
public void insert(int val)//inserts at beginning of list
{
    Node newNode = new Node(val);
    newNode.next = first;
    first = newNode;
}
public Node delete()//deletes at beginning of list
{
    Node temp = first;
    first = first.next;
    return temp;
}
```

Every where on the internet i found almost similar question but are not exactly for boolean,
Someone please help me out.  By the way i am learning c# for 3-4 says.

Comment: it's `Boolean` or `bool`

Comment: try `bool`. This is [tag:C#], not [tag:java]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's `bool` (lowercase *b*) or `Boolean` in C#. Consider using `bool` though since it's much shorter and more consistent with other languages (except Java...).

> The `bool` keyword is an alias of `System.Boolean`.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In C# we dont have keyword boolean, we have it as System.Boolean

Also the bool keyword is an alias of System.Boolean. It is used to declare variables to store the Boolean values, true and false.